# Threading,- GPIO, sleep not in sync python

Tags: gpio, python

I am having problem trying to figure out how to handle 3 threads.

I have 2 threads for blinking LEDs, one is using gpio on device and other one is using remote gpio. I have them in 2 threads, because when remote gpio looses connection it hangs the whole program (no errors just hangs), but I still want local gpio to blink LEDs.
I made 2 thread classes for those.

It works all fine, but only if I run 1 thread only. if I start another thread, 
all my  blinks go out of sync, time.sleep is completely out of sync and LEDs blinks however they want.

Why is that happening ?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Ah, let me see. If you use two threads each of which blinks and sleeps, of course their sleep start end times are out of sync, because that is what concurrent/parallel "async threads" are. If you want to sync two events in two time independent async threads, you need to use "lock" to sync their events (and queue/pipe to communicate). References: (1) https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html.  Happy python multi-processing.  Cheers.

.